# Image is uploading of size 0 byte using php in android

Tags: php, android

I m making an android app to upload the image in mysql database using php. Im saving in directory [$path = "uploads/$id.png";
$actualpath = "http://www.bsservicess.com/photoUpload/$path"].

The problem is that image is uploading to the directory but it showing the size  of image as 0 byte.
I dont know what's the problem.It working perfectly earlier but i dont know why it uploading the size of image of 0 byte now. I try everything but nothing works. If somebody knows the solution please help me.

```
 <?php 
 if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST'){

    $photo= $_POST['photo'];
    $bookname=$_POST['bookname'];
            $phoneNumber=$_POST['phoneNumber'];
            $price=$_POST['price'];

    require_once('loginConnect.php');

    $sql ="SELECT id FROM images ORDER BY id ASC";

    $res = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

    $id = 0;

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res)){
            $id = $row['id'];
    }

    $path = "uploads/$id.png";

    $actualpath = "http://www.bsservicess.com/photoUpload/$path";

    $sql = "INSERT INTO images (photo,bookname,phoneNumber,price) VALUES
     ('$actualpath','$bookname','$phoneNumber','$price')";

    if(mysqli_query($con,$sql)){
        file_put_contents($path,base64_decode($photo));
        echo "Successfully Uploaded";
    }

    mysqli_close($con);
  }else{
    echo "Error";
 }
?


 enter code here> Blockquote

   package com.manali.vivek.userregistration;

   import android.app.ProgressDialog;
   import android.content.Intent;
   import android.graphics.Bitmap;``
   import android.net.Uri;
   import android.os.AsyncTask;
   import android.os.Bundle;
   import android.provider.MediaStore;
   import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
   import android.util.Base64;
   import android.view.View;
   import android.widget.Button; 
   import android.widget.EditText;
   import android.widget.ImageView;
   import android.widget.Toast;

   import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
   import java.io.IOException;
   import java.util.HashMap;


 public class image extends ActionBarActivity implements
  View.OnClickListener    
 {

   public static final String UPLOAD_URL =
    "http://www.bsservicess.com/photoUpload/uploadImage.php";
   public static final String UPLOAD_KEY = "image";

   private int PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST = 1;

   private Button buttonChoose;
   private Button buttonUpload;
   private Button buttonView;

   private ImageView imageView;

   private Bitmap bitmap;

   private Uri filePath;
   EditText et1,et2,et3;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_image);

    buttonChoose = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonChoose);
    buttonUpload = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonUpload);
    buttonView = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonViewImage);
    et1=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.et1);
    et2=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.et2);
    et3=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.et3);
    imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);

    buttonChoose.setOnClickListener(this);
    buttonUpload.setOnClickListener(this);
    buttonView.setOnClickListener(this);
  }

  private void showFileChooser() {
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setType("image/*");
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"), 
 PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST);
 }

 @Override
 protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent 
  data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data
   != null && data.getData() != null) {

        filePath = data.getData();
        try {

            bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(),   
       filePath);
            imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
   }

   public String getStringImage(Bitmap bmp){
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);
    byte[] imageBytes = baos.toByteArray();


   String encodedImage = Base64.encodeToString(imageBytes, Base64.DEFAULT);
    return encodedImage;
   }


   private void uploadImage(){


        class UploadImage extends AsyncTask<Bitmap,Void,String>{

        ProgressDialog loading;
        RequestHandler rh = new RequestHandler();

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            loading = ProgressDialog.show(image.this, "Uploading Image",
         "Please wait...",true,true);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
            super.onPostExecute(s);
            loading.dismiss();

         Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),s,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Bitmap... params) {

            Bitmap bitmap = params[0];
            String uploadImage = getStringImage(bitmap);
            String bookname=et1.getText().toString();
            String  phoneNumber=et2.getText().toString();
            String price=et3.getText().toString();

            HashMap<String,String> data = new HashMap<>();
            data.put(UPLOAD_KEY, uploadImage);

            data.put(Fetch.BOOK_NAME,bookname);
            data.put(Fetch.PHONE_NUMBER,phoneNumber);
            data.put(Fetch.PRICE,price);



            String result = rh.sendPostRequest(UPLOAD_URL,data);

            return result;
        }

    }

    UploadImage ui = new UploadImage();

    ui.execute(bitmap);


    }







 @Override
  public void onClick(View v) {
    if (v == buttonChoose) {
        showFileChooser();
    }
    if(v == buttonUpload){
    uploadImage();

    }


    if(v == buttonView){
        viewImage();
    }
  }


private void viewImage() {
    startActivity(new Intent(image.this, Main.class));
     }
 }
```

> Blockquote

Comment: `$photo= $_POST['photo'];`. What is in $photo? You are doing nothing with it.

Comment: srry i change it to $photo but again it showing the same.plz help me

Comment: What did you change? You dont have to change it. You should use it.

Comment: thanxx for the reply ... and where should i use it ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you double check your code? Your `$photo` is never used and the `$image`that you're trying to decode is null as well.

Comment: Can you post your bitmap to String conversion code on your android app?

Comment: Have you tried changing this line `bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);` to `bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 200, baos);` instead?

Comment: No,it didn't work..instead it give an error that quality should be in b/w 0-100.it will not accept more than 100.

Comment: But have you tried atleast changing the JPEG to PNG?

Comment: Was the image really uploaded? Because while checking at your code, I am able to notice that your `UPLOAD_KEY` is "image" and on your web service when you are trying to retrieve the string of your image, you are using "photo". Try to double check first if these are able to receive the data from your app: `$photo`, `$bookname`, `$phonenumber`, `$price`. Try to dissect on which part of your code gives you a problem. What i usually do is try to walk thru the process from the mobile app to communicating with web service and check which part the problem occurs.

Comment: oh god what a high level of stupid I m, using photo but uploading the image with key 'image'..anyway a big thanxx to fmpsagara .you make my day and save my week to find the error.at this time I don't have words to praise u but again thank u for helping me...

Comment: Is it okay now? I'm glad that I'm able to help you! Best of wishes to you and your application! Take care!